# PublicKey para String

Tags: java, android, apache, base64, rsa

Tenho um servidor que usa RSA e uma app Android.
Quero que o servidor passe a sua PublicKey para a aplicação Android.
Estou a tentar passar a PublicKey como string, mas quando envio algo cifrado com essa chave para o servidor e tento decifrar com a sua chave privada, é lançado um javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error.

Algum dica para saber como posso enviar a Chave Pública do servidor para a app Android?

Código do lado do servidor:

```
PublicKey publicKey = RSA.getPublicKey();
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = fact.getKeySpec(publicKey,X509EncodedKeySpec.class);
String x = Base64.encode(spec.getEncoded());
return x;
```

Código do lado da app Android:

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(x,Base64.DEFAULT);
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = fact.generatePublic(spec);
```

Código para cifrar dados com a PublicKey do lado da app Android

```
byte[] cipherText = null;

    try {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        // Criptografa o texto puro usando a chave Púlica
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(texto.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(cipherText,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Teria como postar o trecho de código responsável para fazer esta transferência e codificação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução!

Orientei-me por aqui e deu bem!

https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-pass-large-data-between-server-and-client-android-securely-345fed551651

Código para enviar a PublicKey (LADO SERVIDOR):

```
PublicKey publicKey = RSA.getPublicKey();
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = fact.getKeySpec(publicKey,X509EncodedKeySpec.class);
String x = Base64.encode(spec.getEncoded());
return x; // retorna String
```

Código para criar uma PublicKey através de uma String (LADO APP ANDROID)

```
 String publicKeyString = x;
 X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(publicKeyString, Base64.DEFAULT));
 KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
 PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);
```

Código para criar uma chave secreta com AES (LADO APP ANDROID):

```
  KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
  keyGenerator.init(128); // AES is currently available in three key sizes: 128, 192 and 256 bits.The design and strength of all key lengths of the AES algorithm are sufficient to protect classified information up to the SECRET level
  SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

Código para cifrar o texto com a chave secreta (LADO APP ANDROID):

```
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted); //retorna String
```

Código para cifrar a chave secreta com a publicKey (LADO APP ANDROID):

```
Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
String encryptedSecretKey = Base64.encodeToString(cipher2.doFinal(secretKey.getEncoded()), Base64.DEFAULT);
return encryptedSecretKey;
```

-------------------------------- ENVIAR texto cifrado e chave cifrada para o servidor ----------------------------

Código para decifrar chave secreta (LADO SERVIDOR)

```
PrivateKey chavePrivada;
byte[] texto = Bse64.decode(texto_cifrado)
byte[] dectyptedSecKey = {};
try {
    //"RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"
    Cipher cipher =Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
    // Decriptografa o texto puro usando a chave Privada
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chavePrivada);
    dectyptedSecKey = cipher.doFinal(texto);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

return dectyptedSecKey;
```

Código para criar uma chave secreta através de um byte[] (LADO SERVIDOR):

```
secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(dectyptedSecKey, 0, dectyptedSecKey.length, "AES");
```

Código para decifrar o texto cifrado com a chave secreta (LADO SERVIDOR):

```
raw = secretKey.getEncoded();
encrypted = Base64.decode(dados);
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
return new String(decrypted); // retorna String TEXTO ORIGINAL
```

Comment: Se possível tente montar uma resposta completa, para que outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema que o seu saibam o que fazer caso o link saia do ar, é possível marca a sua própria resposta como a certa.